# Convert string to matrix (array)

Tags: google-apps-script

i have a string , and i want to put in an array using google apps script, i start to creation function for this but i couldn't do it properly, someone can help me please.
my string is in this form : "key,type, val, key, type, val,key,type, val...."
i want to put in every line of my matrix the key and the type and val.

enter code here

```
function (tasks_data)
{
var data [];
var cpt=-1;
    while(tasks_data.length>0)
    {
    data[cpt ]= new array();
    var key =tasks_data.substring (0,tasks_data.indexof(','));
    var type= tasks_data.substring(0,tasks_data.indexof(','));  
    var val =tasks_data.substring (0,tasks_data.indexof(','));
cpt++;                       
return tasks_data;
}
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

here is a working example, I don't think it needs a lot of explanations...

```
function xxx(){ // this function to test the "real" function
Logger.log(toMatrix('a,b,c,d,e,f,g,h,i,j,k,l,m,n,o,p,q,r,s,t,u,v,w,x,y,z,0'))
}

function toMatrix(tasks_data){
  var matrix = [];
  var row = [];
  var temp = tasks_data.split(',')
  var len = temp.length
    if (len/3 != parseInt(len/3)){return false};// error condition, string must have a length multiple of 3

  for(n=1;n<len+1;++n){
    row.push(temp[n-1]);
     if(n/3==parseInt(n/3)){matrix.push(row);var row=[]};// each 3 items create a new row
     }
   return matrix
}
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you again it works for the example that you give it to me but actually i think my case is object is not string .. so my tasks_data=ADT#hello word#Process#V1#Arabic#1,Paginator1,10,ADT#hello CM#Process#V1#French#1,Paginator2,1,ADT#hello word#Process#V1#Arabic#1,paginator final,120,ADT#hello word#Process#V1#Arabic#1,QC final,120... i thought it was a string but it seems an object because when i tried your function it was erroe :  Cannot find function split in object .do you have idea what i must do ? please .

Comment: Try task_data.to string() to convert it to string before splitting.